# How to make a python script reboot itself

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I work actually on my raspberry 3 **without internet** for my internship.

Firstly I created a python script that I schedule with Cron to update my raspberry's hour every 12h.

Secondly, I have another script should run continually.
But I observed that, when I update the time, my script that run continually, doesn't update its datetime.

So I would like to reboot it, to allow the script to take the time in consideration.
here my script I would like to reboot.

```
from math import *
import pyorbital
from pyorbital import tlefile
from pyorbital.orbital import Orbital
import serial 
import time 
from datetime import datetime
import os
import sat_class
import predict
import rotator_treshold_test

def rotator_set (azel,v):

    if v == False:      
        az = 0
        el = 90

        print(('waiting \n azimuth = %f    elevation = %f\n\n')%(az,el))


    else:
        az = azel[0]

        if azel[1] < 0:
            el  = 0

        else :
            el = azel[1]
        print(('tracking satellite \n azimuth = %f    elevation = %f\n\n')%(az,el))





def satellite_track(): 
    k=0
    saved = [0]
    p = '?'
    b = '?'


    sat = sat_class.Satellite()
    mission = predict.Mission()
    verif = mission.verif 

    if verif == False:
        mission = predict.Mission()
        now= mission.now
        print(now)
        azel = [0,0]                        # we don't need to put azel here we are in waiting mode .
        rotator_set(azel,verif)
        time.sleep(29)




    else :

        mission= predict.Mission()
        print("current time1:   ",mission.now,'\n',mission.start,'     ',mission.end)
        verif1 = mission.verif
        end = mission.end
        now2 = mission.now

        while now2 <= end :

            azel = rotator_treshold_test.az_correct(saved[k])
            rotator_set(azel,verif1)
            saved.append(rotator_treshold_test.az_correct(azel[0]))
            k+=1
            mission = predict.Mission()
            now2 = mission.now
            print(now2)
            time.sleep(0.8)

    ##I would like to reboot my script here





while True :
    satellite_track()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `os.execl()` to restart the program.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execl

Comment: Ho ! Thanks you so much, that was so much easier that I thought .

Comment: No problem! Then please accept the answer and maybe upvote :)

Comment: I don't understand, I tried it the first time on my raspberry, it worked.

Now when I try it,  I have this error message ( " execl() missing 1 required positional argument: 'file'"

I tried to put " os.__file__" as an argument but it doesn't work.

I have the same probleme with "os.execv(os.__file__,args)

And I don't understand which arg to put for " agrs "

Comment: You have to provide the argument to the function, which is the python file you want to reboot (i.e. "./main.py")